# Change values in pandas Series between dates

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas Series() which has daily entries all set to False:

```
d = pd.Series(False, pd.bdate_range("20100101", periods=100, freq="D"))
```

I now want to set the values between the 15th and 20th of each month to True. I generate a Series with indices being the start/end dates and values of True:

```
s = pd.Series(True, pd.bdate_range("20100101", periods=100, freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(14))
e = pd.Series(True, pd.bdate_range("20100101", periods=100, freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(19))
```

At this point `s` and `e` will contain the **s**tart and **e**nd dates between which I want to set the values in `d` to True. I am not sure how to apply this to `d` elegantly.

A complication to this problem is if s and e are random (i.e. it is not always the 15-20 day of the month):

```
import random
sd = random.choice([1,2,3,4])
ed = random.choice([1,2,3,4]) + sd
del sd
del ed

# The delay is still constant for the entire series and not random per row
s = pd.Series(True, pd.bdate_range("20100101", periods=100, freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(14 + sd))
e = pd.Series(True, pd.bdate_range("20100101", periods=100, freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(19 + ed))
```

Comment: If start and end date are random but constant through time, I think you could use the below approaches with `start = 15 + sd` and `end = 19 + ed`. Since you are deleting `sd` and `ed` before adding to `DateOffset` in `s` and `d`, the code throws a `NameError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your existing `pd.Series`, you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) via the `.day` attribute of the `DateTimeIndex`, or use `np.in1d` to the same effect:

```
d[(d.index.day >= 15) & (d.index.day <= 20)] = True

d[np.in1d(d.index.day, np.arange(15, 20))] = True
```

both resulting in:

```
2010-01-01    False
2010-01-02    False
2010-01-03    False
2010-01-04    False
2010-01-05    False
2010-01-06    False
2010-01-07    False
2010-01-08    False
2010-01-09    False
2010-01-10    False
2010-01-11    False
2010-01-12    False
2010-01-13    False
2010-01-14    False
2010-01-15     True
2010-01-16     True
2010-01-17     True
2010-01-18     True
2010-01-19     True
2010-01-20     True
2010-01-21    False
2010-01-22    False
2010-01-23    False
2010-01-24    False
2010-01-25    False
2010-01-26    False
2010-01-27    False
2010-01-28    False
2010-01-29    False
2010-01-30    False
              ...  
2010-03-12    False
2010-03-13    False
2010-03-14    False
2010-03-15     True
2010-03-16     True
2010-03-17     True
2010-03-18     True
2010-03-19     True
2010-03-20     True
2010-03-21    False
2010-03-22    False
2010-03-23    False
2010-03-24    False
2010-03-25    False
2010-03-26    False
2010-03-27    False
2010-03-28    False
2010-03-29    False
2010-03-30    False
2010-03-31    False
2010-04-01    False
2010-04-02    False
2010-04-03    False
2010-04-04    False
2010-04-05    False
2010-04-06    False
2010-04-07    False
2010-04-08    False
2010-04-09    False
2010-04-10    False
Freq: D, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html), but first you need create `Serie` with [`DatetimeIndex.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html):

```
print (pd.Series(d.index.day, index=d.index).between(15,20))
```

```
2010-01-01    False
2010-01-02    False
2010-01-03    False
2010-01-04    False
2010-01-05    False
2010-01-06    False
2010-01-07    False
2010-01-08    False
2010-01-09    False
2010-01-10    False
2010-01-11    False
2010-01-12    False
2010-01-13    False
2010-01-14    False
2010-01-15     True
2010-01-16     True
2010-01-17     True
2010-01-18     True
2010-01-19     True
2010-01-20     True
2010-01-21    False
2010-01-22    False
2010-01-23    False
2010-01-24    False
2010-01-25    False
2010-01-26    False
2010-01-27    False
2010-01-28    False
2010-01-29    False
2010-01-30    False

2010-03-12    False
2010-03-13    False
2010-03-14    False
2010-03-15     True
2010-03-16     True
2010-03-17     True
2010-03-18     True
2010-03-19     True
2010-03-20     True
2010-03-21    False
2010-03-22    False
2010-03-23    False
2010-03-24    False
2010-03-25    False
2010-03-26    False
2010-03-27    False
2010-03-28    False
2010-03-29    False
2010-03-30    False
2010-03-31    False
2010-04-01    False
2010-04-02    False
2010-04-03    False
2010-04-04    False
2010-04-05    False
2010-04-06    False
2010-04-07    False
2010-04-08    False
2010-04-09    False
2010-04-10    False
Freq: D, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you - the above works. Is there an elegant way if s and e are not so regular (i.e. s and e are given as inputs and the pair (s[i], e[i]) could be anything (provided s[i] < e[i] is given)? I can do it with pandas.DataFrame.apply probably but this is not very efficient.

Comment: Sorry, I think I dont understand - you need something like select day 15,17? Or 20, 25 and not between 15 - 17 or between 20 - 25?

Comment: d has daily values, s and e are the dates between which d should be changed. At the moment s[i] and e[i] are predictable and constant but if we introduce some randomness such as s[i] is not always the 15 and e[i] is not always the 20th of the month then the code above will not work.

Comment: I think you can use `print (pd.Series(d.index.day, index=d.index).between(14 + sd,19 + ed))`